# Using sklearn, how do I find depth of a decision tree?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am training a decision tree with sklearn.  When I use:

```
dt_clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

the `max_depth` parameter defaults to `None`.  According to the documentation, if `max_depth` is `None`, then nodes are expanded until all leaves are pure or until all leaves contain less than `min_samples_split` samples.

After fitting my model, how do I find out what `max_depth` actually is? The `get_params()` function doesn't help. After fitting, `get_params()` it still says `None`.

How can I get the actual number for `max_depth`?

Docs: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Access the `max_depth` for the underlying `Tree` object:

```
from sklearn import tree
X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
Y = [0, 1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
print(clf.tree_.max_depth)
>>> 1
```

You may get more accessible attributes from the underlying tree object using:

```
help(clf.tree_)
```

These include `max_depth`, `node_count`, and other lower-level parameters.

Comment: Great answer! Loved it.

Answer (score 6):

The answer according to the docs https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.get_depth is to use the `tree.get_depth()` function.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30905438)