# How to find the max depth in a random forest classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, random-forest

I've a random forest classifier in Python with default parameters. After the classifier is built is it possible to find the max depth in random forest classifier ?

For decision tree classifier we have tree.max_depth().
Example : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499114/using-sklearn-how-do-i-find-depth-of-a-decision-tree)

I know we can set *max_depth* in Random forest classifier but given a classifier with default values can we get this *max_depth* ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

All the trees are accessible via `estimators_` attribute, so you should be able to do something like:

`max((e.tree_.max_depth for e in rf.estimators_))`

(assuming `rf` is a fitted instance of a `RandomForestClassifier`)