# How to Overfit a Decision Tree in scikit-learn on purpose?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Say I have `n` training samples and a binary classification task. I want to train a decision tree of smallest possible depth and having fewest possible total nodes such that the training accuracy on these `n` samples is 100%. In the worst case, this would mean that I have one leaf node per sample. Is there some configuration of parameters in Scikit-Learn's implementation [1] of the `DecisionTreeClassifier` that would let me achieve this?

[1] https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn-tree-decisiontreeclassifier

Comment: `max_depth`: The maximum depth of the tree. If None, then nodes are expanded until all leaves are pure or until all leaves contain less than min_samples_split samples.

Comment: if you dont set the max depth, it will develop the tree to the max

Comment: That's not really true, I think. `max_depth` sets an upper limit on the depth. But if you set (say) `max_depth` = 1000, it is not always the case that `clf.get_depth() == max_depth`.

Comment: which one is smaller :p clf.get_depth() ?

Comment: i dont think you understand how trees work. you have an algorithm trying to split your data into baskets of pure leaves, if it reaches a point where everything is split, it stops. therefore, clf.get_depth won't be as big as the max_depth you set, it will stop once it makes the full tree, which could just use 6 depth.

Answer (score 1):

***Answer***

By reading the documentation you get your answer.

If you dont set a limit to `max_depth` the tree will keep expanding to the deepest leaf.

Also you can check here [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289187/decision-tree-sklearn-depth-of-tree-and-accuracy).